# Display alphabetically

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In my model Feedback I have to retrieve the names of my students in alphabetical order.

Do know you where I must to include this line on my code? `orderBy('name', 'ASC')`.

I had several times a synthax problem...

```
public function index(Request $req) 
    {

    if ($req->search == "") {
        $feedbacks = Feedback::paginate(5);
        return view('admin.feedbacks.index', compact('feedbacks'));

    } else {

        $validated = $req->validate([
            'search' => 'alpha', 
        ]);

        $feedbacks = Feedback::whereHas('students', function($query) use($req) {
            $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $req->search . '%');
        })->paginate(5);

        return view('admin.feedbacks.index', compact('feedbacks'));
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `Feedback::orderBy('name', 'ASC')->...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have belongsTo relationship between Feedback and Student. And you want Feedbacks to te sorted by Student Name. A possible solution is join the both tables.

```
public function index(Request $req) 
    {

    if ($req->search == "") {
        $feedbacks = Feedback::join('students', 'feedbacks.student_id', '=', 'students.id')->orderBy('students.name', 'asc')->select('feedbacks.*')->paginate(5);
        return view('admin.feedbacks.index', compact('feedbacks'));

    } else {

        $validated = $req->validate([
            'search' => 'alpha', 
        ]);

        $feedbacks = Feedback::join('students', 'feedbacks.student_id', '=', 'students.id')->where('students.name','like', '%' . $req->search . '%')->orderBy('students.name', 'asc')->select('feedbacks.*')->paginate(5);

        return view('admin.feedbacks.index', compact('feedbacks'));
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you a lot ^^

Answer (score 1):

You need to do some refactoring over the code. There is no use of having two Feedback objects when you only return one. Another thing you need to consider is the $validaded variable because you don't use that at all in the code that you have there.

I will go with something like this, but of course there is room also to improve it:

```
public function index(Request $req) 
{
    $feedbacks = (new Feedback());
    $feedbacks->orderBy('name', 'ASC');
    if ($req->search == "") {
        $feedbacks->paginate(5);
        return view('admin.feedbacks.index', compact('feedbacks'));

    } else {

        $validated = $req->validate([
            'search' => 'alpha', 
        ]);

        $feedbacks->whereHas('students', function($query) use($req) {
            $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $req->search . '%');
        })->paginate(5);

        return view('admin.feedbacks.index', compact('feedbacks'));
    }
}
```